# Removing domain extension from string using preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex

I want to remove the domain extension `.com` from a string using `preg_replace()`, so for example, if the subject parameter is `facebook.com`, `.com` will be erased from the string.

I thought this would work, `preg_replace(".com", "", $host);`

Unfortunately it returned the error:`Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: No ending delimiter '.' found in`.

I then attempted to escape the period with a backslash (thinking this was the problem), which returned:

`Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash`

Any comments, answers or information would be greatly appreciated!! :).

Comment: you don't need a regex for this, try `str_replace(".com", "", $host)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do have to escape the dot but also regular expressions have to be passed in the form of `/pattern/` that is between slashes

```
preg_replace("/\.com/", "", $host);
```

Side note, there are better recommended ways to do this than using the almighty regular expressions. For example:

```
$url = explode(".","http://static.facebook.com");   
echo $url[1]; // facebook
```

Comment: Thanks :). I'll accept when the timers up. I figured there are probably better ways, and if you're not too busy, I'd love you to reference a better function ;) or indeed add to my current code: `implode('.', array_slice(explode('.', parse_url("http://static.facebook.com", PHP_URL_HOST)), -2));`, which returns `facebook.com`. I attempted to change the last parameter to simply deliver `facebook`, to no avail.

Comment: This seems odd, but also dead simple: reverse the input, then check to see if 'moc.' is at position 0 with `strpos($input,'moc.')`.  Granted, only works if there's nothing after the '.com'.  Other way would be to see if `strpos()` tells you '.com' starts at character position `strlen($input)-4`.  Either way, you avoid regular expressions.

Comment: @Pixelatron i added a cleaner way to do it in my answer, let me know if that will do it

Comment: @Pixelatron indeed, you have some other options there too

Answer (score 0):

You need to include regex delimiters like so:

```
$domain = preg_replace("/\.com$/i", "", $host);
```

Also using $ to anchor the match to end of string, and an "i" for case insensitive matching for "FACEBOOK.COM"